# StringArray error

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I've just start C# (with CodeEval) but i've got a little problem with a StringArray when i execute my programme.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodeEval
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void      fizzBuzz(int x, int y, int n)
        {
            List<string>        list = new List<string>();
            int                 i = 1;

            while (i <= n)
            {
                if (i % x == 0 && i % y != 0)
                    list.Add("F");
                else if (i % x != 0 && i % y == 0)
                    list.Add("B");
                else if (i % x == 0 && i % y == 0)
                    list.Add("FB");
                else
                    list.Add(i.ToString());
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list));
        }

        static int              Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("test1.txt"))
                {
                    while (!file.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string[] line = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                        fizzBuzz(Convert.ToInt32(line[0]), Convert.ToInt32(line[1]), Convert.ToInt32(line[2]));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Le fichier ne peut pas être lu: ");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            return (0);
        }
    }
}
```

My error is in this line

```
fizzBuzz(Convert.ToInt32(line[0]), Convert.ToInt32(line[1]), Convert.ToInt32(line[2]));
```

The test1.txt file have this inside :

3 5 10
2 7 15

When i execute the programme, it works for the first line but then he tried the second line : "The input string format is incorrect"

How can it work the first time but not the second ?
Need help to understand my problem.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: did you look at the values of line[0], line[1], line[2] in the debugger?  What were they?

Comment: line[0] = "3"
line[1] = "5"
line[2] = "10"
the first time.

file[0] = ""
the second time

Comment: No, "3 5 10\n2 7 15\0"

Comment: I think you will find that the /n is causing your problem. You need to change your split to remove it.

Comment: But the ReadLine() just take "3 5 10" and after "2 7 15".
I thinks it's the problem too now, but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about do a little guard in your code to block unwanted white spaces.

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
   String line = file.ReadLine();
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
       continue;
   string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   fizzBuzz(Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]), Convert.ToInt32(tokens[1]), Convert.ToInt32(tokens[2]));
}
```

Comment: @3per thanks for the edit.
I totally forget to change line to tokens :-)

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you very much.
So the ReadLine take the \n like a line, alone ?

Comment: I don't know how your input file looks like. But if you have \n\n it would read twice. (I guess) debug it and you'll see what's in the `line` variable